# PostgreSQL Trigger add / delete data based on the condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm asking for help in a seemingly simple piece like inserting data into another table based on some condition.
So the point is:
There are two tables:
Persons:

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."persons" ( 
    "id" Integer DEFAULT nextval('person_id_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL,
    "surname" Character Varying( 100 ) NOT NULL,
    "name" Character Varying( 100 ) NOT NULL,
    "patronymic" Character Varying( 100 ),
    "date_birth" Date NOT NULL,
    "place_birth" Character Varying( 1000 ) NOT NULL,
    "parent_id" Integer,
    "surnamepat" Character Varying,
    "surnamepat_short" Character Varying,
    PRIMARY KEY ( "id" ) );
```

History of legal representatives:

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."history_legal_representatives" ( 
    "id" Integer DEFAULT nextval('history_legal_representative_id_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL,
    "person_id" Integer NOT NULL,
    "person_parent_id" Integer NOT NULL,
    "modified" Date DEFAULT ('now'::text)::date,
    PRIMARY KEY ( "id" ) );
```

Where are:

```
"person_id" - persons (at table Persons is ID)
"person_parent_id" - legal representative (at table Persons is parent_id)
```

What I'm trying to do:

**When adding** to the table *persons* of the record, which parent_id is not specified, we simply add this entry, if the parent_id is specified, then add *history_legal_representatives* record: - person_id: = persons.id and person_parent_id: = persons.parent_id.

**When editing records** in the table *persons*, if the value of parent_id becomes NULL, delete such a pair from *history_legal_representatives*. (If such a logic is incorrect, please indicate why \ as is more correct)

Code:

**Adding**

```
CREATE TRIGGER addrep BEFORE INSERT ON "public"."persons" FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE addrepresentative()[/SRC]

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.addrepresentative()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
    if NEW.parent_id != NULL then
    insert into history_legal_representatives (person_id, person_parent_id) 
    values (NEW.id, NEW.parent_id);
    end if;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$function$
```

**Deleting**

```
CREATE TRIGGER delrep BEFORE UPDATE ON "public"."persons" FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE delrepresentative()

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.delrepresentative()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
    if NEW.parend_id = null then
    delete from history_legal_representatives where id = NEW.id;
    end if;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$function$
```

Comment: What is required to be done with the code?Any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does not work becouse of NULL comparision in SQL has different syntax (+ typo in delrepresentative) and in delete function you want delete by `person_id`

Fixed code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.addrepresentative()
  RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
    if NEW.parent_id IS NOT NULL then
    insert into history_legal_representatives (person_id, person_parent_id) 
    values (NEW.id, NEW.parent_id);
    end if;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$function$

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.delrepresentative()
  RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
    if NEW.parent_id IS null then
    delete from history_legal_representatives where person_id = NEW.id;
    end if;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$function$
```

Check doc https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-createtrigger.html, i think you need `AFTER` triggers in this case

Comment: Yes....it is a fail, IS NOT NULL or IS NULL - correct, and AFTER - too.